# Java - Retrieve token from response?

Tags: java, android, jwt

I'm authenticating my user by posting my user's credentials to WordPress's Rest API. As a result, it returns a token (JWT) in the JSON response. I'm trying to retrieve that token, but I keep getting an error in the line in which I try and grab the string? The line I'm using:

> String token = response.getString("token");

**Gives me the error:**

> Cannot resolve method 'getString' in 'Response'

What should this line look like instead? My data is returned in JSON format. I'm stumped, as I've seen that syntax in various examples. I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Help is appreciated! Pardon my Java newbness.

**My code:**

```
   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject.put("username", "admin");
                jsonObject.put("password", "password$232");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
            
            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, jsonObject.toString());
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://myurl.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token")
                    .post(body)
                    .build();

            Response response = null;
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                String resStr = response.body().string();
              
                int responseCode = response.code();
             

                if (responseCode == 200) {

                    System.out.println(response);

                    String token = response.getString("token");

                    Log.i("We're logged in!", String.valueOf(responseCode));

                    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);


            }
```

Comment: I would suggest using your debugger, if possible, to examine the `Response` object, and see how the token is actually returned.  It might be as simple as writing `String token = response.header("token");` but the best way to be sure is with your debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that the response object doesn't have an method getString and based on the shared code this code fragment return the json string of the response

```
String resStr = response.body().string();
```

in this case you just need to read the string as an JsonObject and get the properties this way

```
 JSONObject respJson = new JSONObject(resStr);
 String token = respJson.getString("token");
```